# Sending mail and pulling data from app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a situation. HTML Code is standard with three text boxes and one button:

```
<add key="cma_contact_form_email" value="somec@gmail.com"/>
<add key="cma_contact_to_address" value="some@gmail.com"/>
<add key="smtpServer" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
<add key="EnableSsl" value = "true"/>
<add key="smtpPort" value="993" />
<add key="smtpUser" value="some@gmail.com" />
<add key="smtpPass" value="pass" />
```

Code behind:

```
protected void ImageButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e){
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cma_contact_form_email"]);
        msg.From = new        MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["cma_contact_to_address"]);

        msg.Body += "Name: " + txtName.Text + "\n";
        msg.Body += "Email: " + txtEmail.Text + "\n";
        msg.Body += "Message: \n" + txtMessage.Text + "\n";
        msg.Subject = txtName.Text;

        msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpServer"]; //Or Your SMTP Server Address
        smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPort"]);

        smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["smtpPass"]);
        //Or your Smtp Email ID and Password
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(msg);
            lblPost.Text = "Thank you, your question has been submitted to our CMA heldesk.";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lblPost.Text = "Error occured while sending your message. "  + ex.Message;
        }

        placeholder.Visible = false;
        msgplaceholder.Visible = true;
    }
```

Normally this should work, but I get a time-out error. Anyone know where the catch might be? Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you get the timeout error? Could you post an exception message, a stacktrace or explain better where this happens? Apart from that, a timeout usually sounds like network issues.

Comment: Timeout error smells like your server has no network access to the smtp server...Are the required ports open?

Comment: @ArveSystad he is most likely getting the timeout on `smtp.send()` call

Comment: Use the `MailSettings` element instead of putting the settings in the `AppSettings` section. Your code will be a lot shorter than this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx

Comment: Are you sure that your SMTP port is 993? I think this is the IMAP port.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following method to check if connection is permissible before doing an actual send to email and you should also handle **SmtpException**. It has a *StatusCode* property, that will tell you why the Send() failed.

you can call the below method like this

```
if(TestConnection("smtpServerAddress",port))
  SendEmail();

public static bool TestConnection(string smtpServerAddress, int port)
    {
        IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(smtpServerAddress);
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(hostEntry.AddressList[0], port);
        using (Socket tcpSocket = new Socket(endPoint.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            //try to connect and test the rsponse for code 220 = success
            tcpSocket.Connect(endPoint);
            if (!CheckResponse(tcpSocket, 220))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // send HELO and test the response for code 250 = proper response
            SendData(tcpSocket, string.Format("HELO {0}\r\n", Dns.GetHostName()));
            if (!CheckResponse(tcpSocket, 250))
            {
                return false;
            }

            // if we got here it's that we can connect to the smtp server
            return true;
        }
    }

  private static bool CheckResponse(Socket socket, int expectedCode)
{
    while (socket.Available == 0)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    byte[] responseArray = new byte[1024];
    socket.Receive(responseArray, 0, socket.Available, SocketFlags.None);
    string responseData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(responseArray);
    int responseCode = Convert.ToInt32(responseData.Substring(0, 3));
    if (responseCode == expectedCode)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**GMAIL Settings**

- Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
- Gmail SMTP user name: example@gmail.com
- Gmail SMTP password: password
- Gmail SMTP port: 465
- Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes

Comment: There is no need to complify, the try/catch is correct in his code, the problem is just settings

Comment: Agreed that port is incorrect. Though try/Catch is not correct. And if you are using multiple servers for sending email it is better to complify.

Comment: I changed smtp port to 465 but same error "Error occured while sending your message. The operation has timed out."

Comment: @mikrimouse have you added the code to check if you have actually access to the server?

Comment: I have some error in the second method with senddata and encode

Comment: if you have added the code that i have given, does your Testconnection succeeds?

Comment: where will i put first IF can you implement it in my code and then paste it here ? Encoding does not exist and same with DataSend, i included system.net.encoding library.

Comment: call it before smtp.Send(msg); like if(TestConnection(smtp.Host,smtp.Port)) smtp.Send(msg);

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** The port that you have mentioned in your settings is for IMAP,

**Resolution:** Correct port for **GMAIL SMTP** is [port 465](http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm) instead of [port 993](http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_IMAP_Settings.htm) which is for [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol).

Comment: Why -1 for this answer?

Comment: your answer is correct, i would recommend you to clarify it though. let me edit it

Comment: I changed port to 465 and same error , "Error occured while sending your message. The operation has timed out."